# Repeating image in a canvas with responsive height

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to create a canvas where I have an image as a background that repeats horizontally and adapts the height automatically.

I've managed to repeat the background image following the x-axis but I'm unable to make the height responsive.

This is my code so far:

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

const bg = new Image();
bg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100";

const draw = () => {
  const ptrn = ctx.createPattern(bg, "repeat-x");
  ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="200"></canvas>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

> **TLDR**: I would like to be able to have an image within my canvas that repeats horizontally and its height is responsive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is confusing. you're talking about repeating an image and the title is about repeating an image yet the question seems to be about making the height of the canvas itself "responsive." which is it? and what do you mean by "responsive," as that word usually applies to the width of a device, not it's height.

Comment: Let's say I have a responsive canvas that adapts to the users browser (!00% height and 100% width). Inside the canvas I have an image that repeats horizontally. What I'm trying to achieve is having that image with a responsive height (the canvas one for instance) and also repeating horizontally... Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the explanation in the comments answers your question. Feel free to ask for clarification.

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// First stretch the canvas so we can get 
// the full size of teh browser window
cvs.style.height = '100vh';
cvs.style.width = '100vw';

// Now adjust actual canvas size to match
const {width, height} = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
cvs.height = height;
cvs.width = width;

const bg = new Image();

// Should always wait for onload 
// before drawing to prevent race condition.
bg.onload = ()=>{

  var x=0;
  while(x < cvs.width){
    ctx.drawImage(bg, x, 0, 100, cvs.height);
    x += bg.width;
  }

  // draw the image a bunch of times
  // var x=0, y=0;
  // while(x < cvs.width && y < cvs.height){
  //   ctx.drawImage(bg, x, y);
  //   x += bg.width;
  //   if(x > cvs.width){
  //     x = 0;
  //     y += bg.height;
  //   }
  // }

};
bg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was supper close to what I needed. Removing the if statement inside the `while` and replacing the current drawImage with `ctx.drawImage(bg, x, y, 100, cvs.height);` make it work! Give it a try and tell me what you think :)

Comment: like that? if that is the correct answer please mark it as such.

Comment: Indeed :) I was waiting for your edit to mark it as correct :D Thanks for the help @I wrestled a bear once

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you want to fill the height and repeat horizontally, is that correct?

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100";

var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

var imgWidth = 200;
var imgHeight = 200;

const draw = () => {
  tempCanvas.width = imgWidth;
  tempCanvas.height = imgHeight;
  tCtx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  const ptrn = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas , "repeat-x");
  ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};
bg.onload = () => {
  draw();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="200"></canvas>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting up the image size to match the canvas size just like that:

bg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200";

Cheers! :)